# Behavior of TF_FORCE_GPU_ALLOW_GROWTH=true in tensorflow serving with multiple models (Saved model format)

Tags: docker, tensorflow-serving, nvidia-docker

I have a question about the TF_FORCE_GPU_ALLOW_GROWTH flag option with tensorflow serving.

I am able to run multiple models in a docker container with TF serving. In order to limit the GPU usage, I passed the TF_FORCE_GPU_ALLOW_GROWTH=true flag as an environment variable. So as the model server loads initially, it takes up some 250 MiB , and after my first inference request, it expands to occupy around 6.4 GB of GPU memory (out of 10GB total GPU mem).
This is irrespective of whether one model was loaded or multiple were loaded.

My question is that

- how do we check the individual memory consumption of each model?
- Does the server load all models to GPU memory which is why the usage does not cross 6.4 GB limit?
- Does tf serving have any functionality to unload models from GPU after the inferencing has been done?